# Radon Nikodym Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, independence

I have a question regarding the Radon-Nikodym Theorem (RNT). Let's say we have two independent random variables $X,Y$ with distributions $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$. If X has a distribution function ($f_x$), does the RNT guarantees that, for instance, $X-Y$ also has a distribution function ($\phi$)? Or is it necessary that $Y$ also has a distribution function ($f_y$)?

My thoughts on this were that, as $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$ is $\theta = \mu_x\times\mu_y$. The measure $\theta$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_x$ (and $\mu_y$). So, can we apply the RNT to conclude that there $(X,Y)$ has also a distribution function?